# Do you know any ready-to-start substrate based blockchain that I can take as fundament for my blockchain?

Tags: substrate-node, blockchain

Is there any ready open blockchain to start? I need the one with staking and with opportunity to make new tokens. To send tokens with other users in this blockchain. Or maybe someting close to this.
I tried to make it from substrate-node-template, but I dont understand how to add new pallets like pallet_staking or others. Or maybe you can recommend any clear tutorial except the official substrate one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Here i am trying to show you easy way to add pallet into substrate node template**

First you need to add dependency of your pallet which you want to add into substrate-node-template in the `runtime/Cargo.toml` then add the pallet into the`runtime/src/lib.rs` then Implement the configuration trait for the  pallet into `runtime/src/lib.rs`at the last add the pallet to the `construct_runtime.`
Then build it by using ****cargo build --release****